# Safari password combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I've noticed that when using Safari's auto-generated passwords feature, passwords are always of the same form: 3 sets of six alphas each, separated by dashes. Furthermore, there is always 1 digit somewhere within the sets, and 1 uppercase letter.

For example:

`jawsyk-ryDbic-4zakwa`

There is never more than 1 uppercase and 1 digit in the output password.

My first thought is that the total number of possible passwords is $26^{17}*10*18$, representing the 17 alpha-only positions, 1 numeric, and then accounting for the position of that numeric somewhere in the permutation. However, my gut tells me the presence of a single uppercase letter should complicate the formula. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Choose the location of the digit from among the 18 positions.  Choose which digit it was.  Choose the location of the uppercase letter from among the remaining 17 positions.  Choose which uppercase letter it was.  Then from left to right for all remaining positions, choose which lowercase letter it was.  Your answer is off by a factor of 17 assuming your assumptions are all correct.

Comment: Note that many systems will explicitly avoid certain lookalike characters, such as O and 0, or I 1 and l.  That of course would just adjust the available character set.